# SSRS Count Rows of Previous Group (Table in Matrix)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, count

Using the sample below, I am looking for a way how to count the number of rows in the table in the previous group. My report is setup using a Matrix and a table ("Tablix3") in the data region of the matrix.

The column groupings are called "DayOfTheWeek" and "AMPM".

In the area with the blue box around it, I need the PM group to count the number of rows in "Tablix3" for the AM group on that day, which is 2. When the value is greater than 1 I will use expressions to alter the background colour accordingly as the bottom right pink background shouldn't be there.

I am using SSRS 2008.

[image: Sample report]

Comment: I've managed to do a quick fix by changing the underlying query and providing a count of AM and PM based on the day and location for each row the query returns. Still interested to know whether this could have been achieved through SSRS expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  You have to do it in the query.